# How to find id of the last element/object in a meteor collection?

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-autoform

I have a collection in meteor that comes from a form(Form is created using aldeed:autoform). I want to extract the id of the last element/object (or most recent entry) of the collection. How can I do that??

Edit: Here is what the autoform looks like:

```
 PlayersList = new Mongo.Collection("players");
 PlayersList.allow({
     insert: function(){

     }
});
PlayersListSchema = new SimpleSchema({
name: {
    type: String,
    label: "Name",

  },
  age: {
    type: Number,
    label: "Age"
  },
  gender:{
    type: String,
    label: "Gender"

  },
  country: {
    type: String,
    label: "Country of Birth",

  },
  race: {
    type: String,
    label: "Ethnicity",

  },
  income: {
    type: Number,
    label: "Income",

  },
  education: {
    type: String,
    label: "Education Level",

  },
});
PlayersList.attachSchema(PlayersListSchema)
```

With Each form an id is generated. I want the id of the last form in the database.

Comment: can you show some code and what you've tried?

Answer (score 1):

```
var lastEntryId = [].slice.call( *meteorCollection* ).reverse()[0].id;
```

or if that looked to short and easy, you can choose a shorter & faster one:

```
var lastEntryId = [].slice.call( *meteorCollection* ).pop().id;
```

or you could use a true Spartan, even faster and truly laconic:

```
var lastEntryId = [].pop.call( *meteorCollection* ).id;
```

You'll get an empty string if id property attribute has not been set.

Comment: Tried each of them but it doesn't seem to work. I get the error: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Comment: that's only possible, if your variable "meteorCollection" feed doesn't contain elements with property id by default nor by definition. That is: you have non-DOM element's that don't contain id property at all.

Comment: Isn't id created by default? I want to use the default property

Comment: Your error report states clearly that the property you are requesting from it, is not present in the object you are feeding the expression with.
You need to make sure that the object you are selecting the property from is providing you the id property on it's last element collection.

Answer (score 0):

```
var recent_entry = PlayersList.find().sort({_id:-1}).limit(1);
```

where '-1' in sort is for Newest to oldest arrangement, if you use '1' it's vice-versa.

Comment: I still get the error: Uncaught TypeError: PlayersList.find(...).sort is not a function

Comment: Ok. This should work, PlayerList.find({},{$sort : {_id : 1}},{limit : 1});       I am not on my desk right now, so i have not tried this practically.